# React Datepicker Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'usestate')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, null, react-datepicker

I'm creating a test for the react datepicker, but nothing I do seems to make it work correctly. Whenever I try adding a datepicker to my function, it throws an error.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

const DatePickerTest = () => {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

    return (
        <div>
            <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)} />
        </div>
    );
}

DatePickerTest.defaultProps = {};

export default DatePickerTest;
```

I am completely stumped on this. I already checked the version of react, and I believe 18.2.0 is compatible with even the highest version of the datepicker. I checked all other existing code, and it really only happens when I add the datepicker in. The rest of the code works great even if I add other objects rather than the DatePicker.

Comment: Are you using React Server Components ? Perhaps you need to add `"use client"` at the top; Otherwise the code, as is, should work.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I tried that, and I'm still getting that error for some reason. I don't understand what's going on at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the necessary CSS for react-datepicker?

> > import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

?

Comment: Yeah, I added that. I still get the usestate error.